# Contacts of random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk, random

We want to estimate, in $d$-dimensional space, the typical number of contacts of random walk of length $N$, as $N\to \infty$. Consider a sphere containing a random walk of length $N$, whose radius will scale with $\sqrt{N}$ and the volume will scale as $N^{d/2}$ in $d$ dimesions.

Now consider a polymer consisting of $N$ monomers modelled as a random walk.  When we consider the monomers as independent particles confined in a volume $V_d$. What will be the probability that a given pair of monomers meet in the same point scale with $N$?

Comment: What are "contacts" in the context of this question?

Comment: We speak of a contact when two monomers are being at the same place, i.e. it is more like a node of the random walk.